# CSS Float property makes DIV not clickable

Tags: css, jquery

I have a div which contains other divs and several CSS classes applied to it.
Now, it seems like everything works only on the text part of my div, where there is no text, nono of the events nor css works.

All Jquery events and CSS properties works only on text contained in the div and not on the whole div.
Even if I just try to apply a `cursor: pointer;` in the css for that div or even attach an event handler like this:

```
$("#myDiv").on("click", function (event) {
    alert("works");
});
```

I tried setting a `background-color`, setting a `background-image`, I tried `click` event and `on` event. Nothing works.

#### HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="meatBlock" class="blocks">
        PORK & BEEF
    </div>
    <div id="cheeseBlock" class="blocks">
        CHEESE & ONIONS
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

Here is the CSS on one of the internal Divs that don't work:

```
.blocks
{
    float: left;
    width: 310px;
    height: 141px;
}
#content
{
    max-width: 975px; 
    min-width: 975px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}
```

If I remove the `float:left` from the css altogether, it works. I can't understand why because I can't reproduce it in jsfiddle.

Anybody as any suggestions and knows what is going on here?
I need it to work only in IE8+, so no worries about chrome or firefox.

Comment: Please attach the CSS of that `<div>`

Comment: Has your div fixed dimensions? If not it collapses when empty.

Comment: It's not empty, OP says it has text, and it should work even without dimensions set.

Comment: Use debugger tool (like Inspect Element in Chrome) just see Matched CSS Rules in Element Tab. you will know which CSS is inherited.

Comment: I added the css of one of the internal divs that don't work, also the inherited one like it says when I inspect the element in IE. I don't know if it's important to know the parents css

Comment: look a this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5xFEJ/1/

Comment: yeah but that's not my case. I said I can't replicate in jsfiddle I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

It was `float:left` indeed.

To fix this issue I put a `<div style="clear: both">` at the end of all the divs that use the float and that magically change the behaviour of the divs back to normal